# How do I remove an active outline from jquery accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion, outline

I am using Jquery Accordion. The active link has an outline.
I have tried using css:

```
#accordion a:focus
 { outline: none; }
#accordion a:active 
{outline: none; font-weight:bold;}
```

and also

```
#accordion a:-moz-any-link:focus 
{ outline: none; }
```

None of these seem to work. Can anyone advise a setting or another option to remove the dotted outline around the active links?

Comment: there are like 20 accordion plugins out there can you provide a link?

Comment: PS: outline:none is not a good idea in general for accessibility: http://outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 23):

You need to figure out the tab element's class being applied by the widget. For instance,

```
.ui-state-focus { outline: none; }
```

works on the most recent version of jQuery UI, but on an earlier version like the 1.6, you'd need to use this:

```
.ui-accordion-header {outline: none;}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your CSS stylesheet and it will take care of the blur/focus outline:

```
#accordion .ui-state-focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I like how this solution is specific to the accordion and won't affect other jquery scripts. +1

Answer (score 3):

I have only seen this happen with header tags so far. To remove it, add the code

```
h1, h2, h3, h4{outline:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQueryUI's Accordion, http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/, you shouldn't have a problem with these types of outlines. If you are though, you could do the following:

```
$(".ui-accordion-header a").click(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

In fact, this method will work with just about any accordion plugin - just be sure to modify the selector to target the links responsible for expanding/collapsing the data panels.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to override the styles applied by jQuery UI elements, I usually add a stylesheet that I load after the jQuery UI stylesheet and put my overrides into it, using the same selectors so that I know that my styles will take precedence.  In this case look for the styles associated with the accordion or the widget state and override them.

Answer (score 0):

SORTED:

amend the css to - ui-state-focus

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to press F5 once in a while... and make sure you are not editing other files than you think you are.