# Remove outline from active jQuery UI tab?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to remove the outline on an active jQuery UI tab (or at least change the color).

Working from [this example,](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
<style>
    #tabs .ui-state-focus
    {
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

(based on a tip from this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086657/how-do-i-remove-an-active-outline-from-jquery-accordion)).

What's the trick to removing the outline from an active tab?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't believe it's the class `focus` that you need to target, it's the CSS psuedo-class `:focus`

`.ui-state-focus:focus { outline:1px dotted red !important }`

if that works, go with `{outline:none}` to remove it. You are sort of jacking up your accessibility by worrying about it though, FYI.

Comment: Yes it does... click inside the Result window, and hit <TAB> (you should see a red dotted line around the first tab element). Maybe we're chasing different issues?

Comment: Ah, cool, I see that now.  But in mac-chrome, clicking a tab puts a blue border around the same tab.  I am trying to change that.

Comment: It has something to do with how fine-grained your selector is. Using `*:focus { outline:none }` works, but so does `#tabs ul li a:focus {
    outline:none;
    /* outline-color:red */;
}` - paste that CSS into your fiddle, you'll see. Mac Lion & Chrome tested

Comment: To prove my statement above replace your class-based '.ui....' selector in the fiddle you passed me with `#tabs ul li a:focus, #tabs ul li:focus`. Don't change the CSS. Now, on `click/active`, and `<TAB>` what once was fuzzy light blue will be dotted red line.

Answer (score 24):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here are two examples (I suggest option 2):

**Option 1**

Remove the outline from all elements that use the `.ui-widget` class:

```
.ui-widget * { outline: none; }​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjmQT/1/).

**Option 2**

Make the outline color transparent:

```
#tabs li a
{
    outline-color: none;
}​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcEGK/).

Comment: On a Mac, `outline-color:transparent` actually changes the color from the default blue to a graphite color. (OS X Lion + Chrome)

Comment: @Dawson, agreed. Simply replace with `outline: none;`

Comment: This worked for me where the accepted answer did not for some reason.  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I managed to remove it with

```
.ui-tabs-anchor:active, .ui-tabs-anchor:focus{
     outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove the outline only on a specific tabs then I suggest you use the following:

```
$("#tabs ul li").css({'outline': 'none'}); // where #tabs can be any specific tab group
```

inside the script tag of your html.

Comment: congrats to your first answer! make sure to have a look at the [markdown (message formatting syntax) help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the outline by specifying `outline-width: 0;`

```
#tabs li a
{
    outline-width: 0;
}​
```

---

A more generic solution without using IDs would be:

```
.ui-tabs ul li a
{
    outline-width: 0;
}​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ebCpQ/

Comment: This requires I know the div id ahead of time. I am dynamically creating tabbed panels (with auto-generated ida), so I believe I would have to dynamically insert css to use this solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this to prevent possible initial tab order focus too:

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-visited a, .ui-state-focus a, .ui-state-focus:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This removed the blue underline on the currently focused tab!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
a:focus { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear, the outline appears on the  element inside of the ul.ui-tabs li.ui-tabs-nav.
Most of above examples forgot to mention this: so here is a working answer for the original question:

```
.ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-focus a {
    outline: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xJ9Zr/5/

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, none of this worked for me.  I had to add a border to get the outline (or maybe it was a blue border) to go away:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-state-active
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important; /*Or any other color*/
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```